# Ros2 import regular python modules from where

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 20.04
ros2 foxy
This may be a dumb question but I have not yet run into it so I feel the need to ask. If I am writing a python node and I want some modules from pip (or conda I suppose) such as pyserial, to what do I install the module in order to be able to use it in a ros2 node? If I wanted to use pyserial in a regular python script for a project, I would go to my venv that I use for misc projects and pip install pyserial from that environment, then use it. Am I supposed to run

```
python3 -m pip install -U pyserial
```

just for my system python? Because I've always made some sort of venv for my projects because gumming up the system with random modules usually results in me breaking something or causing some sort of package conflict. I know I can run limited ros functions from a venv (done it through an anaconda env once before to be able to run tensorflow2 in python3 in ros melodic) but I cant see that being something that is regular practice.
For C++ I can just put the header/source files in a library type folder inside the ros package so that isn't an issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365628/ros2-import-regular-python-modules-from-where/) by [seandburke99](https://answers.ros.org/users/59327/seandburke99/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2020-11-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are several options available for using third-party python packages in your ROS nodes.

Based on this question (and several similar ones), we have added some documentation to cover these use cases: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Using-Python-Packages/

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2020-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0